# Nutch Fetcher aborting with N hung threads

Tags: nutch

I am using Nutch-1.4 for crawling websites. the issue i am facing in crawling is fetcher always aborts with N hung threads.
Entries in log file are,

> INFO  fetcher.Fetcher - -activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0
>   INFO  fetcher.Fetcher - -activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0
>   INFO  fetcher.Fetcher - -activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0
>   WARN  fetcher.Fetcher - Aborting with 1 hung threads.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm facing a similar one and would like to know what fixed this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some requests seem to hang, despite all intentions. This happens when the Fetcher threads don't perform any activity for a long time. See line 932-936 [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/nutch/fetcher/Fetcher.java.html).

**Steps to deal here:**

1. check what urls were been crawled just before this message was logged in log file. (see fetching... statements in the log).
2. Are those urls taking lot of time to load ? (try to `wget` those urls from the same machine.
3. Is the content of those pages big ? (check their size))
4. The timeout value is typically 600 seconds. Increase the value of configuration [mapred.task.timeout](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/mapred-default.html) in mapred-site.xml of hadoop configuration. (For local mode, simply add the value in nutch-site.xml with larger value)
5. Are you performing any operation (say parsing) which is taking really lot of time ? Is the application hanging somewhere ?

I think if u work of these things, u can get it fixed.

also read [this](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Nutch-1-2-fetcher-aborting-with-N-hung-threads-td2411724.html) and [this](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Nutch-1-1-Crawl-is-slow-hangs-and-aborts-eventually-td1402770.html).

Comment: Hi Tejas - from step # 4 above, when you said add mapred.task.timeout in mapred-site.xml and for local mode - add the value in nutch-site.xml. So you mean all the values in nutch-site.xml should be copied over to mapred-site.xml of hadoop when running HBase in Pseudo distrbuted mode for Nutch 2.2.1?

Comment: @archer Not all. If you are running hadoop in pseudo distrbuted mode, add 'mapred.task.timeout' to mapred-site.xml with a higher value. Thats all you need to do. Being honest, thats the last resort for this problem. Increasing timeout seems enticing to get quick fixes but points 1-3 must be considered for serious production deployments.

Comment: Tejas - I checked # 1-3, the url just before I got this hung on N threads is very simple url and I wget and it took like a fraction of section. I have set timeout value as a last resort as well. I am not able to go further beyong 4th iteration. I am using bin/crawl script with nutch 2.2.1.

Comment: @archer you need to run crawl only with the problematic url and figure out from logs what step in fetch is responsible for the hang task. Adding extra log statements would make it more easier.

Comment: Tejas - Nutch logs stopped in the parsing stage now. On the terminal it said,"Aborting with 8 hung threads" and when I checked the Hbase log to see if it is still connected, this is what I have - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384899/hadoop-hbase-pseudo-mode-regionserver-disconnects-after-some-time