# Hadoop HBase Pseudo mode - RegionServer disconnects after some time

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, nutch

Please find the attached screenshot of Hbase-master log. I have tried all sorts of settings yet I couldn't overcome this issue. I made sure I don't have 127.0.1.1 in my /etc/hosts.

I am using **Apache Hadoop 0.20.205.0 and Apache HBase 0.90.6 in Pseudo distributed**. I am using Nutch 2.2.1 and trying to store crawled data in HBase Pseudo mode. I am using bin/crawl all-in-one command. Please help!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try killing the master then start it up again... The dead server state is in memory...
hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, no it did not help. I had to updgrade Hadoop from 0.20.205.0 to 1.2.1